# Push notification: How can I send push notification to a specific device using Pubnub?

Tags: ios, node.js, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pubnub

Here is code of nodejs which I am using on server side, I am using only one chennal.

**Code:**

```
var pubnub = require("pubnub")({
ssl           : true,  
publish_key   : "pub-c-e2f2e008-92ce-4abc-a9fc-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
subscribe_key : "sub-c-3c272090-0370-11e5-aefa-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
geo           : true
});

exports.sendNotification=function(req,res){
var responseData={
                message:"Send notifications",
                data:null
            };

var message = {
"aps":{
    "alert":"Your Message: sent from nodejs server",
    "sound":"push1.wav"
 }
};
pubnub.publish({ 
channel   : 'apns',
message   : message,
callback  : function(e) { 
                console.log( "SUCCESS!", e );
                res.json(responseData); 
            },
error     : function(e,data) { 
                console.log( "FAILED! RETRY PUBLISH!", e ); 
                responseData.message="FAILED! RETRY PUBLISH!";
                res.json(responseData);
            }

});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [this documentation](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/objective-c/iOS/tutorial/apple-push-notification.html).

Devices are registering for pushes on channel. If you want to target specific device, you have to use multiple channels.

I also suggest to use [this method of sending pushes](http://www.pubnub.com/community/discussion/498/sending-apns-and-gcm-messages-to-subscribers-and-mobile-push-notification-services-in-one-api-call) because in case of adding GCM functionality you will have to send only one message to queue that will be received by both devices